# be better to do/ be better doing/

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, infinitives

> 1- l'll get engaged like all the others. Get married. Maybe ***it's 
>   better doing*** things the way everyone does. (original)
>
> 2- l'll get engaged like all the others. Get married. Maybe ***it's
>   better to do*** things the way everyone does.
>
> 3- ***It’s always better being*** safe than sorry.
>
> 4- ***It’s always better to be*** safe than sorry. (original)
>
> 5- Wouldn't ***it be better putting*** a time-limit on the task? (original)
>
> 6- Wouldn't ***it be better to put*** a time-limit on the task?
>
> 7- You ***are better eating*** just a small snack than hurrying a main
>   meal. (original)
>
> 8- You ***are better to eat*** just a small snack than hurry a main
>   meal.

Is there a difference in meaning between these versions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two idiomatic constructions here:

"It is better" + infinitive, e.g.

> It is better to be safe than sorry.

"You are better **off**" + present participle, e.g.

> You are better off eating just a small snack than hurrying a main meal.

(And you can substitute any other personal pronoun in the second form - I, he, she, we, etc.)

So sentences 1, 3, 5, 7 and 8 are ungrammatical.

Comment: I quoted some of the sentences from here: (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/be-better-doing-something-it-is-better-doing-something)

Comment: Huh. All I know is, those examples don't sound natural to me. Maybe in another dialect they would be more common. But I guess another thing to keep in mind is, just because it's in a dictionary doesn't mean that people commonly use it.